# Why does Discordjs embed image fail for Tenor images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am trying to display gifs from tenor with discordjs. I have read similar posts that requires `setImage` an actual file.

```js
export const PINCH=[
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-pinch-face-gif-14114215.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/hestia-cheek-pinch-cute-danmachi-is-it-wrong-to-try-to-pick-up-girls-in-a-dungeon-gif-19893304.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/horimiya-anime-shota-hori-siblings-gif-19989089.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-cute-pinch-tanakakun-is-always-listless-gif-14725930.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-hibike-euphonium-asuka-tanaka-oumae-kumiko-pinch-gif-16488937.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/squishy-cheeky-anime-gif-15322355.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/rikka-takanashi-so-cute-chuunibyou-pinch-face-anime-gif-13451272.gif",
    "https://tenor.com/view/slap-butts-anime-hit-gif-14179587.gif"
]
```

I have set images in an array and NOT making a fetch call to get images.
Here is the code that builds the emebed image.

```js
const getEmbedWithUser= (user: User, mention: User)=>{
    const image=PINCH[Math.floor(Math.random()*PINCH.length)]
    return new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .setAuthor({
            name: `${user.username} pinches ${mention?.username}!! Aaa, that hurts`,
            iconURL: user.avatarURL() || ""
        })
        .setImage(image);
}
```

Images are in loading state and then shows a discord poop image.
How do I solve this?
[image]

But I give direct links like this..

```
.setImage("https://c.tenor.com/M9fgYFTTCqQAAAAC/anime-cute.gif");
```

The image shows and works as expected.
[image: pic]

Comment: Maybe try using direct links to the images ?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed direct links works. But I want random links from array

Comment: What's stopping you from making a list of random direct links ?

Comment: I want the links to be from this `PINCH` array which are direct links.

Comment: Then simply replace the links with their direct version ?

Comment: These aren't direct links? Can you give me an example. These are direct links, coz when I click on them they open up a new tab to the file.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the links with their *direct* version, like so:

```js
export const PINCH = [
    "https://c.tenor.com/GJMfGDUMv1QAAAAC/anime-pinch-face.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/HarnS903A_YAAAAC/hestia-cheek-pinch.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/OTrBBINLVswAAAAC/horimiya-anime.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/M9fgYFTTCqQAAAAC/anime-cute.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/aApaaPTuEvYAAAAC/anime-hibike-euphonium.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/cg9Yp4fu7VQAAAAC/squishy-cheeky.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/pQQWwZE_OqEAAAAC/rikka-takanashi-so-cute.gif",
    "https://c.tenor.com/bHE5Txlp5-8AAAAC/slap-butts-anime.gif"
];
```

Comment: How do you get the direct links? It worked.

Comment: Open up the links in your browser then copy the addresses :)

Comment: Oh, right! Thats where I went wrong. Thanks